# what payload data exactly means in nodejs

Tags: node.js, payload

Can someone explain me the meaning of payload data in nodejs. I am bit confused here about the term payload data.
I am using payload.somevariable. I thought I am getting the payload data from the HTTP request.

Comment: Usually it just a serialized JSON data.

Comment: Usually, the payload data is the request or response body, it might be wrapped with some boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Payload data in NodeJs is just packets or chunks of data sent to the server and that cannot be accessed ordinarily. They can be accessed when we decode them, using the `string_decoder` module and some of its methods like the `on` and `end`.

In a framework of NodeJS known as Express.js, an example is body-parser module. With this module we can access these chunks of data so as to use them to perform CRUD operations on a database.